# Almost complete intersection ideal and $d$-sequence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings

In a Noetherian local ring $R$, an ideal $I$ is called an *almost complete intersection ideal* if $\mu(I)=\text{ht}(I)+1$.

**Q) Is it true that $I$ is generated by a $d$-sequence?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the comments to the previous answer (see the next answer) I give the following counterexample for the case where $d$-sequences are defined without considering permutations:

Let $R=K[x,y]$ and consider the ideal $(x^2,y^2,xy)$. It can be seen that no permutation of $x^2,y^2,xy$ is a d-sequence, e.g. $(xy):x^2y^2\neq (xy):x^2$. But in order to prove that the ideal is not generated by any $d$-sequence it is better to  use theorems. In view of  the theorems of the cited papers below, the ideal generated by a  $d$-sequence is an ideal of linear type i.e. its Rees Algebra and Symmetric Algebra are equal. Now, by, e.g., using Macaulay2, one can see that the ideal $(x^2,y^2,xy)$ is not of linear type.

[Theorem, page 472, *Craig Huneke*, MR 608547 [**Powers of ideals generated by weak $d$-sequences**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(81)90276-3), *J. Algebra* **68** (1981), no. 2, 471--509.]

[Page 5, *J. Herzog, A. Simis, and W. V. Vasconcelos*, MR 686942 [**Koszul homology and blowing-up rings**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=686942), *Commutative algebra (Trento, 1981)* 79--169.]

Answer (score 2):

Not, necessarily. For example, in $K[x,y]$, $x^3,xy^2$ is not a $d$-sequence, but it generates an almost complete intersection. However, in some cases, the answer is positive. For example, see (5) of the cited paper below.

*Craig Huneke*, MR 563225 [**On the symmetric and Rees algebra of an ideal generated by a $d$-sequence**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(80)90179-9), *J. Algebra* **62** (1980), no. 2, 268--275.

Comment: Is not xy2,x3 a d-sequence? I think it is. (xy2:x3) and (xy2:x6) both are generated by (y2).

Comment: $(x^3):xy^2=(x^2)$, but $(x^3):x^2y^4=(x)$, therefore $x^3,xy^2$ is not a $d$-sequence.

Comment: But the ideal J=(xy2,x3) is almost intersection and generated by d-sequence.

Comment: It depends on how you are going to define a sequence to be a $d$-sequence. For instance, in the Huneke's paper which I cited above,  to define $d$-sequences, colon ideals are considered for any permutation of the sequence.